# Deriving Via With Standalone Deriving

Tags: haskell, deriving, derivingvia

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here:

```
data Vector2D u = Vector2D { 
    _x :: u, 
    _y :: u 
} deriving stock (Show, Eq, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

{-# INLINE addVector2 #-}
addVector2 :: (Additive a) => Vector2D a -> Vector2D a -> Vector2D a 
addVector2 (Vector2D { _x = x1, _y = y1 }) (Vector2D { _x = x2, _y = y2 }) = 
    Vector2D { _x = x1 + x2, _y = y1 + y2 }

instance (Additive a) => Additive (Vector2D a) where
    (+) = addVector2

newtype Square a = Square {
    unpackSquare :: Vector2D a
} deriving stock (Show, Eq)
```

So far, so normal (Additive is defined in the algebra package but is pretty self-explanatory).

However, now I want to be clever using DerivingVia and StandaloneDeriving and I can't even get the next line to compile

```
deriving instance (Additive a) => Additive (Square a) via (Vector2D a)
```

But that gets me

```
    * Expected kind `k0 -> * -> Constraint',
        but `Additive (Square a)' has kind `Constraint'
    * In the stand-alone deriving instance for
        `(Additive a) => Additive (Square a) via (Vector2D a)'
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm running GHC 8.6.2

Comment: For what it is worth, I prefer your syntax with `via ...` at the end to the one actually accepted by GHC, where `via` comes earlier.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's

```
deriving via (Vector2D a) instance (Additive a) => Additive (Square a)
```

The way you wrote it, `via` looks like a type variable

```
deriving instance (Additive a) => Additive (Square a) via (Vector2D a)
-- <==>
deriving instance forall a via. (Additive a) => Additive (Square a) (via) (Vector2D a)
```

and this produces a kind-mismatch error, as `Additive (Square a) :: Constraint` is already saturated, but you have applied it to two more arguments.

This is backwards from the shorthand form:

```
data T' = ...
  deriving Class via T
```

Comment: Is this anywhere in the users' guide? I haven't been able to find it!

Comment: [It is here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#deriving-strategies). It says, in general, *all* strategies look like `deriving strat instance head`, and `via _` is one example of a strategy.

Comment: Hmmm. That takes a lot more reading between the lines than it should. Maybe I'll remember to submit a PR to improve the docs.